# Quick Sort - First Element As Pivot

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I'm studying Quick-Sort and I am confused as to how it works when the first element is chosen as the pivot point.

I am trying to trace the first step in the Quick-Sort algorithm, to move the pivot (15) into its appropriate position.

Example: [15, -7, 22, 7, 21, 34, -13, 19]

My understanding:

```
15, -7, 22, 7, 34, -13, 19
#   ^                   ^
```

Move left-pointer to first element larger than the pivot. 1 comparison (move to 22).
Move right-pointer to first element smaller than the pivot. 1 comparison (move to -13).

```
15, -7, 22, 7, 34, -13, 19
#       ^           ^
```

Swap elements at the pointers (22, -13).

```
15, -7, -13, 7, 34, 22, -13, 19
#       ^           ^
```

Move left-pointer to first element larger than the pivot. 2 comparisons (move to 34).
Unable to move right-pointer to first element smaller than the pivot (cannot past the left-pointer.

```
15, -7, -13, 7, 34, 22, -13, 19
#               ^   ^
```

Swap elements at the pointers (34, 22).

```
15, -7, -13, 7, 22, 34, -13, 19
#               ^   ^
```

This is where I am stuck. My understanding is that the pivot should then be swapped with 22, but that doesn't seem correct?

How do I move the pivot (15) into its appropriate position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a random pivot is selected and moved to the first location.
After swapping -13 and 22, your pointers should be on 7 and 34.

7 and 34 are correctly placed.
Also 7 and 34 are adjacent, so time has come to put the pivot in its correct place.

array looks like this

*15, -7, -13, 7,* **34, 22, 19**

So now you know that all elements after 34 are greater than 15.
So swap the first element before 34 with the pivot.

So array looks like

7, -7, -13, **15,** 34, 22, 19

Now all on left of 15 are lesser than 15 and all on right of 15 are greater than 15